# Слово в единственном или множественном числе?

Tags: php

Есть несколько существительных:

- Аэрозоль
- Бальзам
- Гранулы
- Таблетки
- Эмульсия

Возможно ли определить, слово находится в единственном или множественном числе? Например, "таблетка" - единственное число, а "таблетки" - множественное число.

Comment: Да, стоит же метка PHP. Например, функция возвращает true - слово в ед. числе, false - слово во множественном.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### phpMorphy

phpMorphy – библиотека морфологического анализа, реализованная на платформе PHP.

Возможности
phpMorphy позволяет решать следующие задачи:

- Лемматизация (получение нормальной формы слова)
- Получение всех форм слова.
- Получение грамматической информации для слова (часть речи, падеж, спряжение и т.д.).
- Изменение формы слова в соответствии с заданными грамматическими характеристиками.
- Изменение формы слова по заданному образцу.
- Поддерживаемые языки: Русский, Английский, Немецкий (AOT). Украинский, Эстонский (на основе ispell). Есть возможность добавить поддержку других языков при помощи myspell словаря.

Поддерживаются различные кодировки: 
все однобайтовые (windows-1251, iso-8859-* и т.п.)
Unicode кодировки - utf-8, utf-16le/be, utf-32, ucs2, ucs4.

Находится она [здесь](http://phpmorphy.sourceforge.net/dokuwiki/).

---

---

Если же вы не хотите использовать готовые библиотеки, то надо написать функцию для этого.
Написать функцию для всех существительных в русском языке <strike>очень трудно</strike> невозможно. Но для большинства можно определить. Если слово оканчивается на 'и' или 'ы' то множественное; во всех остальных случаях единственное.

**Но предупреждаю, работать это будет не везде. Так что советую использовать библиотеку.**
Но для данных вами существительных этот алгоритм подходит.